# How to create two equal views on one perspective

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I need a few views with different content (files) on one perspective, but i can't register new view with same name. How it is possible to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set the "allowMultiple" attribute to "true" in your view's extension in plugin.xml.
2. Use secondary ID to distinguish between instances. Open the views with `IWorkbenchPage.showView(String viewId, String secondaryId, int mode)` and use `IViewSite.getSecondaryId()` to find which instance you are in.

See [this post](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53368.html) for details.